# Mouse-over a badge link should show a badge details tooltip

Tags: feature-request

When a badge is linked, for example, like this: [Civic Duty](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/32/civic-duty), it would be useful to see the **badge description** without navigating to another page.

The most common way would be to handle it like mouseover on a username in comments or like hovering the actual badge -- with a **tooltip**.

### Variants

**a) Simple**

[image: simple]

*This is a text-only variant, implemented simply by using existing HTML functionality (`title` attribute of the `a` element).*

**b) Rich**

[image: rich]

*More effort, but also more information provided to the user.*

### Questions

1. do we need it?
2. which one is to your liking?

Comment: Doesn't it already show a tooltip? White on black.

Comment: @Ranveer, erm, no. Mouse over a badge name on this page: http://stackoverflow.com/election and tell me if you see any description popup/tooltip. I (on Chrome on Windows) don't, hence the [feature-request].

Comment: Oh! So you're talking about any page in general.

Answer (score 1):

1) I would like it (because I have gone searching for that info)

2) Either would be fine.